# How do I multiply an element's tuple that I got from arg(*arg)? (Python 3)

Tags: python, arguments, tuples, multiplication, keyword-argument

So I'm a beginner in Python and I have this task. So, I have a tuple of random numbers, my job is to make a function that I can use to multiply these tuple of numbers, my mentor recommends me to use args (*args).

~ThankYou~

Comment: Import the `operator` and `functools` modules. Then: `functools.reduce(operator.mul, args)`

Comment: `math.prod((1,2,3)) == 6`. (This was new in Python 3.8; I just learned about it myself the other day.)

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop:

```
def prod(args):
    mul = 1
    for x in args:
        mul *= x

    return mul
```

And call like:

```
print(prod((1,2,3))
```

Comment: @chepner thanks for saving the day, what a foolish mistake `0*x=0` OMG!!!